# Troubleshooting an NDSolve::ndfdmc error message

Tags: differential-equations

Τhe following code

```
Ay[ξ_] := A0*(1 - κ^2)^.5*Exp[-(δ ξ - φ)^2/2] Sin[ξ]
Az[ξ_] := A0*κ*Exp[-(δ ξ - φ)^2/2] Cos[ξ]
Ay1[ξ_] := D[Ay[ξ], ξ]
Az1[ξ_] := D[Az[ξ], ξ]
j1 = DSolve[{y''[ξ] + r^2 y[ξ] == r/Δ (α2 - Az[ξ]) - 1/Δ Ay1[ξ], 
    z''[ξ] + r^2 z[ξ] == -1/Δ Az1[ξ] - r (α1 - Ay[ξ]), y[0] == yo, 
    y'[0] == Pyo/Δ, z[0] == zo, z'[0] == Pzo/Δ}, {y, z}, ξ]

Py[ξ_] := D[y[ξ] /. j1, ξ]
Pz[ξ_] := D[z[ξ] /. j1, ξ]
P1[ξ_] := Py[ξ]^2 + Pz[ξ]^2
A0 = 7; δ = 1/15; r = 1; φ = 5; κ = 1/Sqrt[2]; α1 = 0; α2 = 0; Δ = 1; 
yo = 0; zo = 0; Pyo = 0; Pzo = 0;
j2 = NDSolve[{x'[ξ] == P1[ξ], x[0] == 0}, x[ξ], {ξ, 0, 1.6*2 π/δ}]
```

produces the message

> NDSolve::ndfdmc: Computed derivatives do not have dimensionality consistent with the initial conditions. >>

How can I fix this so that I can plot `x[ξ]`?

```
Plot[x[ξ] /. j2, {ξ, 0, 1.6*2*π/δ}, 
 PlotStyle -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Comment: Please do not dump a block of code and ask us to debug it. Explain what your problem is in a little more detail and reduce it to a minimal example. Have you looked into your equations to see if it makes any sense? Because we can't help you there unless you tell us what it is that you're trying to do. Also, please see the [editing help](mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: I am asking the question for the first time so added the block for completeness. My Problem is that the mathematical solution that comes out from DSolve has to be used in NDSolve. But the problem is with the NDSOLVe Which gives above error.

Comment: Yes, adding code is always good. I meant, could you also add the mathematical equations (in latex) that are behind your DSolve/NDSolve? The error message points to some inconsistency, which could've very well been your transcribing error...

Answer (score 1):

Replace the second part for:

```
Py[ξ_] := D[y[ξ] /. j1[[1]], ξ]
Pz[ξ_] := D[z[ξ] /. j1[[1]], ξ]
P1[ξ_] := Py[ξ]^2 + Pz[ξ]^2
A0 = 7; δ = 1/15; r = 1; φ = 5; κ = 1/Sqrt[2]; α1 = 0; α2 = 0; Δ = 1; 
yo = 0; zo = 0; Pyo = 0; Pzo = 0;
j2 = NDSolve[{x'[ξ] == P1[ξ], x[0] == 0}, x[ξ], {ξ, 0, 1.6*2 π/δ}]

Plot[Re[x[ξ] /. j2], {ξ, 0, 1.6*2 Pi/δ}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I appreciate your help, but could you please tell me what this symbolize, so that for future works, I should be vigilant.

Comment: @VikramSagar `j1`is a List. You need to get the first element that's all